# Sylow 2-subgroup and Sylow 3-subgroup of $D_{24}$ (of order $48$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

> Find Sylow 2-subgroup and Sylow 3-subgroup of $D_{24}$

I have found
$n_2 = 1$ or $3$ and $n_3 = 1$ or $4$ or $16$, where $n_2$ & $n_3$ are the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups and Sylow $3$-subgroups respectively, but I am unable to pinpoint the exact solution. I am having difficulty in understanding $D_{24}$ also. Can someone help with this?

Comment: For help see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098757/number-of-sylow-2-subgroups-in-dihedral-group-d-20) and related ones. For $p=3$ see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460952/let-p-be-an-odd-prime-number-and-let-n-be-a-positive-integer-divisible-by-p-sh?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Do you mean $|D_{24}|=24$ or $|D_{24}|=48$?

Comment: @Shaun the latter

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $D_{n}\cong\Bbb Z_n\rtimes\Bbb Z_2$.